# regex replace and add hyphen before first zero

Tags: regex

Input1: RC000030034

Replace1: RC-000030034

Input2: RC100003282

Replace2: RC1-00003282

Looking to add a hyphen before the first 0 in the string.

- Input will always have 11 characters.
- Final output will always be 12 characters.
- Never will have alpha characters after the hyphen.

Comment: Where is your attempt to solve this issue? You gave us zero code.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: `^(.*?)0` replace with `$1-0`

Comment: Maybe using a positive lookahead to assert the characters and the lenght of the string [`^(?=[A-Z\d]{11}$)([^0]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/rQHD1Y/1) and replace with group 1 and a hyphen `\1-`

Answer (score 0):

Based on this : "Looking to add a hyphen before the first 0 in the string."

example in javascript:

```
> var re = /^([^0]*)0(.*)$/
> "RC000030034".replace(re,"$1-$2")
'RC-00030034'
```

in bash (echo + sed):

```
$ echo 'RC00030034' | sed -e 's/^\([^0]*\)0\(.*\)$/\1-\2/'
RC-0030034
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = input.replace("0", "-0")
```

or equivalent code in your language

Most languages provide some kind of replace method for strings. The example above works in javascript, it will replace the first occurence of '0' by '-0'.
In python, there is a replace() which replacess *all* occurrences; there, you must use an optional argument to indicate a maximum number:

```
output = input.replace("0", "-0", 1)
```

In perl, you could use a regular expression:

```
$input =~ s/0/-0/;
```

Putting all your strings in a file (each string on a separate line) you can use the following shell command:

```
perl -ne 's/0/-0/; print' inputfile
```

Now, suppose your input allows for strings like RC0A00001234, where the hyphen should be before the second 0, behind the A (because we 'Never will have alpha characters after the hyphen'). 
Then the command has to change into:

```
perl -ne 's/(0\d*)$/-$1/; print' inputfile
```